# Django, Running 'createsuperuser' on Visual Studio Command-line Error

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

**Hi,**

I want to user Python 3.7 and Django 2.1 in Visual Studio.
I just create a new Django project from **Visual Studio.** It creates the Python-Django project.

> But when I try to run *'createsuperuser'* command from command-line on
>   Visual Studio, I am getting this long error text.

**I have the Python 3.7 and Django 2.1 version on my computer so I think It is not about the version.**

How can I solve this problem?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\management\commands\createsuperuser.py", line 59, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 13, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 23, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 396, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 533, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "c:\users\misafir\source\repos\DjangoWebProject7\DjangoWebProject7\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 526, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File ".\DjangoWebProject7\urls.py", line 23, in <module>
    django.contrib.auth.views.login,
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'
```

Comment: Could you show your urls.py file?

Answer (score 4):

`django.contrib.auth.views.login` has been removed in django 2.1. From the [Release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/releases/2.1/#features-removed-in-2-1):

> contrib.auth.views.login(), logout(), password_change(), password_change_done(), password_reset(), password_reset_done(), password_reset_confirm(), and password_reset_complete() are removed.

You should now use the class-based view [`django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) in your urls, e.g. in its simplest form:

```
path('login/', LoginView.as_view()),
```

Comment: This helped me. Here's the import I used `from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView`

Answer (score 0):

> module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'

the error is clearly showing.... 
i hope you are using Authentication Module that why you are facing this